# Elk Stack GPG13

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Does anyone know of any pre-built sets of rules for the ELK stack that are used for the GPG13 PMCs? Looking around at various SIEMs at the moment, and whilst I know rules can be built for GPG13, to save time we were hoping there was "out of the box" rules available.

Comment: by rules, do you mean grok pattern?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori honestly, we currently don't know anything about ELK stack at the moment; we're still researching SIEMs in general so I don't know if it'll be about grok patterns.